# Cant seem to extract normal strings from scrapy even when i am using a loader

Tags: python, scrapy

I cant seem to  extract strings from scraping a website even though i am using a loader. 
When using one loader things are working all right ( for reviews), but the problem seems to be for the second loader i am using (ProductDescriptionLoader)

Attached below is the code

filename items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join,Compose

class FlipkartTestspiderItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = Field()
    review=Field()
    url=Field()
    productName=Field()
    productPrice=Field()
    productCategory=Field()
    productDescription=Field()
    productPriceCurrency=Field()

class ProductDescriptionOrReviewLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    default_item_class = FlipkartTestspiderItem
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    # this in case the review field contains multiple values
    review_out = Compose(MapCompose(lambda s: s.strip()), Join())

class ProductDescriptionLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    default_item_class = FlipkartTestspiderItem
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(lambda string: string.strip())
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

filename spider/flipkart_spider.py

```
...
def parse(self, response):
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
for review in hxs.select('//p[@class="line bmargin10"]'):
    rl = ProductDescriptionOrReviewLoader(response=response, selector=review)
    rl.add_xpath('review', 'text()')
    rl.add_value('url', response.url)
yield rl.load_item()
loader = ProductDescriptionLoader(response=response)
loader.add_xpath('productCategory',"//div[@class='line fk-lbreadbcrumb']")
loader.add_xpath('productName',"//div[@class='title fk-hidden']")
loader.add_xpath('productDescription',"//div[@class='line extra_text nprod-specs']//table")
loader.add_xpath('productPrice','//meta[@itemprop="price"]')
loader.add_xpath('productPriceCurrency','//meta[@itemprop="priceCurrency"]')
loader.add_value('url', response.url)
yield loader.load_item()
```

I can post the pipeline code, but the post will become too lengthy. All  i am doing in the pipeline is writing the scraped values to a yaml file.
Here is a sample yaml file:

```
{productCategory: !!python/unicode "<div class=\"line fk-lbreadbcrumb\">\n       \
    \             <span><a href=\"/\">Home</a> /</span>\n                        \
    \    <span><a href=\"/computers\">Computers</a> /</span>\n                   \
    \         <span><a href=\"/laptops/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g\">Laptops</a> /</span>\n \
    \                               <span><a href=\"/laptops/dell~brand/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g\"\
    >Dell Laptops</a> /</span>\n                                <strong>Dell XPS 13\
    \ Laptop (2nd Gen Ci7/ 4GB/ 256GB SSD/...</strong>\n            </div>", productDescription: !!python/unicode '<table
    style="padding-top: 6px; width:100%;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top" class="nprod-speclist"><ul
    class="fk-ul-disc"><li>Core i7 (2nd Gen)</li><li>Windows 7 Home Premium</li></ul></td><td
    style="vertical-align:top"><ul class="fk-ul-disc"><li>256 GB SSD</li><li>4 GB
    DDR3</li></ul></td></tr></table>', productName: !!python/unicode '<div class="title
    fk-hidden">Dell XPS 13 Laptop (2nd Gen Ci7/ 4GB/ 256GB SSD/ Win7 HP)</div>',  productPrice: !!python/unicode '<meta
    itemprop="price" content="93587">', productPriceCurrency: !!python/unicode '<meta
itemprop="priceCurrency" content="INR">'
```

I want the !!python/unicode symbols to disappear. How do i do that ?

Comment: Do you really need the HTML as output? or would you prefer text representation?
Also I don't get what "!!python/unicode" is in your case, and where it comes from, if it's literally what you really get in the YAML file

Comment: Hello, I prefer text but haven't yet figured out how to convert those html snippets to text. All i know is !!python/unicode should not be there (I am assuming it is coming from python because there is no code in my repo that prepends !!python/unicode

Comment: For `productCategory` you could try `loader.add_xpath('productCategory',"//div[@class='line fk-lbreadbcrumb']//a/text()", Join(u", "), unicode.strip)`

Comment: `!!python/unicode` comes from PyYaml http://pyyaml.org/ticket/11 , and apparently you can use `.safe_dump`

Comment: You are correct. If you had given that as an answer you would have gotten some points. Thanks a ton for your help and guidance.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not here for points :) but I can still post it as an answer for others (and yourself) to up/down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!!python/unicode` comes from PyYAML (see http://pyyaml.org/ticket/11), and apparently you can use `.safe_dump()` to not have it

If you want to get text representation of these HTML snippets, you can use XPath with `text()` node tests. For example, for the `productCategory` field, you could use:

```
loader.add_xpath('productCategory',
    "//div[@class='line fk-lbreadbcrumb']//a/text()",
    Join(u", "), unicode.strip)
```

Another option if you want to keep a bit more of the HTML structure in your fields is to use an HTML-to-Markdown library, such as https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text

Comment: Everything works almost perfectly except for the fact that i get this error exceptions.NameError: global name 'Join' is not defined. Google is not helping

Comment: You have to have `from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join` near your other import statements

Answer (score 0):

import re

```
re.sub("!!python/unicode", "", s)
```